# CppUnit, very simple test code crashed, why?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, cppunit

I am learning CppUnit, and my code coredumped when calling TestRunner::run(). That's line 34 in the below code. I can not see anything wrong. It is almost identical to the sample code in the CppUnit cookbook.

```
#include <iostream>  
#include <cppunit/TestCaller.h>  
#include <cppunit/TestSuite.h>  
#include <cppunit/ui/text/TestRunner.h>  
using namespace std;  

//class MyFixture: public CppUnit::TestFixture {  
class MyFixture{  
public:  
   MyFixture() {cout<<"MyFixture:: ctor()"<<endl;}  
   ~MyFixture() {cout<<"MyFixture:: dtor()"<<endl;}  
   void setUp() {cout<<"MyFixture::Setup()"<<endl;}  
   void tearDown() {cout<<"MyFixture::tearDown()"<<endl;}  
   void testFunc1() {cout<<"MyFixture::testFunc1()"<<endl; m=1; CPPUNIT_ASSERT(m==1);}  
   void testFunc2() {cout<<"MyFixture::testFunc2()"<<endl; m=2;}  
   int m;  
   static CppUnit::TestSuite * CreateSuite();  
};  

CppUnit::TestSuite * MyFixture::CreateSuite()  
{  
   CppUnit::TestSuite * suite = new CppUnit::TestSuite("My TestSuite for MyFixture");  
   suite->addTest(new CppUnit::TestCaller<MyFixture>("MyFixture::testFunc1", &MyFixture::testFunc1));  
   suite->addTest(new CppUnit::TestCaller<MyFixture>("MyFixture::testFunc2", &MyFixture::testFunc2));  
}  

int main()  
{  
   cout<<"point 1000"<<endl;  
   CppUnit::TextUi::TestRunner runner;  
   runner.addTest(MyFixture::CreateSuite());  
   cout<<"point 7000"<<endl;  
/*Line34*/   runner.run();  


   cout<<"point 8000"<<endl;  
}
```

The output:

```
  cppunit$ ./test_runner   
  point 1000  
  MyFixture:: ctor()  
  MyFixture:: ctor()  
  point 7000  
  Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

The stack trace:

```
(gdb)bt  
-0  0x00733cc9 in CppUnit::TestRunner::WrappingSuite::run(CppUnit::TestResult*) ()  
   from /usr/lib/libcppunit-1.12.so.1  
-1  0x0073170a in CppUnit::TestResult::runTest(CppUnit::Test*) () from /usr/lib/libcppunit-1.12.so.1  
-2  0x00733af0 in CppUnit::TestRunner::run(CppUnit::TestResult&, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) () from /usr/lib/libcppunit-1.12.so.1  
-3  0x00736d2b in CppUnit::TextTestRunner::run(CppUnit::TestResult&, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) () from /usr/lib/libcppunit-1.12.so.1  
-4  0x00736da2 in CppUnit::TextTestRunner::run(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, bool, bool, bool) () from /usr/lib/libcppunit-1.12.so.1  
-5  0x080494dd in main () at test_runner.cpp:34
```

The compile line: g++ -g -o -Wall test_runner test_runner.cpp -lcppunit
It compile successfully without any warning.
If I turned on "-Wall", it gave error:

```
......
(.data+0x4): multiple definition of `__dso_handle'  
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.5.2/crtbegin.o:(.data+0x0): first defined here  
test_runner: In function `_init':  
(.init+0x0): multiple definition of `_init'  
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.5.2/../../../crti.o:(.init+0x0): first defined here  
/tmp/ccgzqvu9.o: In function `MyFixture::CreateSuite()':  
/home/fzhao/temp/cppunit/test_runner.cpp:22: multiple definition of `MyFixture::CreateSuite()'  
test_runner:/home/fzhao/temp/cppunit/test_runner.cpp:22: first defined here  
/tmp/ccgzqvu9.o: In function `main':  
/home/fzhao/temp/cppunit/test_runner.cpp:29: multiple definition of `main'  
test_runner:/home/fzhao/temp/cppunit/test_runner.cpp:29: first defined here  
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.5.2/crtend.o:(.dtors+0x0): multiple definition of `__DTOR_END__'  
test_runner:(.dtors+0x4): first defined here  
/usr/bin/ld: warning: Cannot create .eh_frame_hdr section, --eh-frame-hdr ignored.  
/usr/bin/ld: error in test_runner(.eh_frame); no .eh_frame_hdr table will be created.  
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status  
make: *** [test_runner] Error 1
```

Comment: Did it crash, or did it not build? Pick one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that the signature for the function is:

```
CppUnit::TestSuite * MyFixture::CreateSuite()
```

shouldn't you be *returning* something (`suite` would be my first guess)?

By not returning *anything,* the line:

```
runner.addTest(MyFixture::CreateSuite());
```

is going to add a very dodgy pointer to your `runner`.

---

And the reason you're probably getting those errors when you insert `-Wall` is because:

```
g++ -g -o -Wall test_runner test_runner.cpp -lcppunit
       \______/ \___________________________________/
```

will try to output your executable to the file `-Wall` by linking together `test_runner`, `test_runner.cpp` and the `cppunit` library. Perhaps you meant to type:

```
g++ -g -Wall -o test_runner test_runner.cpp -lcppunit
             \____________/ \_______________________/
```

(I'm assuming here that the compile line you gave was the one where the errors occurred since it actually *has* `-Wall` in it ).

Comment: But, why when I turn on "-Wall", g++ gave out so many error and failed? It reported "multiple definition" of main(), _init, _dso_handle? Now that's my major question. I'll edit the post to reflect this.

Comment: @John, see my second section. If you have `-Wall` where you said you have it, you're trying to combine the `test_runner` executable, `test_runner.cpp` and the `cppunit` library. Since the executable already has everythin defined, you going to get duplicate symbol errors. Change it so the `-o` and `test_runner` are adjacent, and in that order.

Comment: Ooops again. That's another stupid mistake. Thanks for the help

Comment: No problems, @John. Just one thing. It's not usually a good idea to change your question fundamentally since it "breaks" answers that have already been done. By all means _augment_ the information in there (by adding another code block) but adding the return statement to the existing code means that the question/answers no longer match, rendering them useless for future visitors. I've reverted the question to fix this.